# Convert Multiple if condition into Ternary Operator

Tags: c#, ternary-operator

I want to convert below condition to ternary

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(objModel.Status))
{
    if (objModel.Status == "0")
    {
        Model.Sort = "Result1";
    }
    else if (objModel.Status == "8")
    {
        Model.Sort = "Result2";
    }
    else 
    {
        Model.Sort = "Result3"; 
    }
}
```

I have tried as below but it went upto if and else not else if

```
Model.Sort = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Status) 
    ? (Model.Status == "0" ? Retult1 : string.Empty) 
    : string.Empty;
```

Comment: It sounds pretty straightforward, have you tried to do this? Also, this sounds like a terrible idea - this code rewritten with ternary conditional operators will look horrible.

Comment: And what problems are you having doing that?  What did you try, and what problems did you have with that attempted solution?

Comment: Is your final version meant to be "Result3"? Currently your second `if` part is unnecessary.

Comment: *"I want to convert below condition to ternary"* Please don't. Don't convert code to something hard to read for the sake of saving a couple lines of (free) space in your file.

Comment: Also, the original version of your code can't be converted to a ternary because nothing happens if the string is null/empty. Ternary's must always return a value.

Comment: Imagine what the above code would look like if you add three new conditions. Then imagine what the ternary would look like.

Comment: Is the else case `Result3` or `Result2`?

Answer (score 0):

you can have ternary operator like this

```
a ? b : c ? d : e
```

to get this:

```cs
if (a) {
  b
}
else if (c) {
{
  d
}
else {
  e
}
```

in your case

```cs
objModel.Status == "0" ? Model.Sort = "Result1" : objModel.Status == "8" ? Model.Sort = "Result2" : Model.Sort = "Result2";
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your code using ternary operators like this:

```
Model.Sort = string.IsNullOrEmpty(objModel.Status)    //    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Status))
    ? Model.Sort                                      //        Model.Sort = Model.Sort;
    : objModel.Status == "0"                          //    else if (Status == "0")
        ? "Result1"                                   //        Model.Sort = "Result1";
        : objModel.Status == "8"                      //    else if (Status == "8")
            ? "Result2"                               //        Model.Sort = "Result2";
            : "Result3";                              //    else Model.Sort = "Result3";
```

Where the first condition represents the `if` condition, and then each statement after a `:` operator that is a comparison represents an `else if`, and finally the result after the last `:` represents the final `else` assignment.

The first condition is kind of a "dummy" condition (because if it's true nothing really changes*), but is required if we want to include the `IsNullOrEmpty` check in the ternary operations, since the ternary operator has to return a value in both the `true` and `false` cases.

*I'm not sure if the dummy assignment would get optimized away or if the setter is called in that "dummy" case. If the setter is called then potentially this could have a different effect than your original code, depending on what the setter code does.*

Answer (score 0):

Keep a local variable for simplification

```
var x = objModel.Status;
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(x))
{
    Model.Sort = x=="0" ? "Result1" :
        x=="8" ? "Result2" :
            "Result3";
}
```